# How do I use bash-specific syntax using `watch`?

Tags: python, bash, sh, watch

I can successfully run this [`pyrg`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrg) command in Linux:

```
python -m unittest discover |& pyrg

> ...
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Ran 3 tests in 0.001s
> 
> OK
```

But not this one:

```
watch -n 1 --color 'python -m unittest discover |& pyrg'

> Each 1.0s python -m unittest discover |& pyrg
>
> sh: 1: Syntax error: "&" unexpected
```

Also I cannot find out how to use `pyrg` in the other form with `python -m` instead of an actual script:

```
watch -n 1 --color pyrg python -m unittest discover

> Usage: pyrg [options] TEST_SCRIPT.py
>      : python TEST_SCRIPT.py |& pyrg
>
> pyrg: error: no such option: -m
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: @Cyrus thanks, retagged

Comment: `sh` does not know `|&` but `bash`.

Comment: @Cyrus I tried `watch -n 1 --color 'bash python -m unittest discover |& pyrg'
` to no avail. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use bash-specific syntax, you need to make sure you run your command with the bash shell:

```
watch -n 1 --color 'bash -c "python -m unittest discover |& pyrg"'
```

Actually, you can remove a level of quoting:

```
watch -n 1 --color --exec bash -c 'python -m unittest discover |& pyrg'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `man bash`:

> If |& is used, command's standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to command2's standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for  2>&1 |.

So, this should work:

```
watch -n 1 --color 'python -m unittest discover 2>&1 | pyrg'
```